# How can I add a mutual exclusion constraint with Ecto?

Tags: elixir, ecto

I've got a schema with two fields, `a` and `b`, and I want exactly one of the fields to be required. That is, if `a` is provided `b` should not be, and vice versa.

Is there a way to elegantly represent this with Ecto changeset validations? Something like this:

```
schema "foo" do
  field(:a, :string)
  field(:b, :string)
  field(:c, :string)

  timestamps()
end

def changeset(transaction, attrs) do
  transaction
  |> cast(attrs, [:a, :b, :c])
  |> validate_required([:c])
  |> validate_mutual_exclusion([:a, :b])
end

defp validate_mutual_exclusion(changeset, fields) do
  # What goes here?
end
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can count the number of fields that are present and check if that equals 1:

```
defp validate_mutual_exclusion(changeset, fields) do
  present = Enum.count(fields, fn field -> present?(get_field(changeset, field)) end)

  case present do
    1 -> changeset # ok
    _ ->
      # add an error to each field
      Enum.reduce(fields, changeset, fn field, changeset ->
        add_error(changeset, field, "exactly one of these must be present: #{inspect(fields)}")
      end)
  end
end
```

`present?` just checks if the value is `""` or `nil`:

```
def present?(nil), do: false
def present?(""), do: false
def present?(_), do: true
```

Comment: Thanks, that's great!